# I get a type mismatch error

Tags: vbscript, type-mismatch

I am working on a project to improve my logic skills that calculates a Quarterbacks passer rating. I have tries all my skills at debugging this problem and I am still at a loss. First I will show you a look at my code.

```
'Prompt Statements
'error handling to see if the previous 5 prompted inputs are numbers

Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Choose a Quarterback : "
QB = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine

'attempts and completions loop
'attempts

do
  Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many attempts did " & QB & " throw: "
  attempts = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
  if IsNumeric(attempts) then
    attempts = CInt(attempts)
  else
    Wscript.StdOut.Write "You did not enter a number. Please try again."
  end if
  loop while IsNumeric(attempts) = false

  'completions
do
  do
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many completed passes did " & QB & " throw for: "
    completions = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
    if IsNumeric(completions) then
      completions = CInt(completions)
    else
      Wscript.StdOut.Write "You did not enter a number. Please try again."
    end if
  loop while IsNumeric(completions) = false
  if attempts < completions then
    Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Completions can not be more that attempts please try again."
  else
    exit do
  end if
loop while attempts < completions

'yards
do
  Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many yards did " & QB & " throw for: "
  yards = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
  if IsNumeric(yards) then
    if yards <= 32767 then
      yards = CInt(yards)
      exit do
    else
      if yards > 32767 then
        yards = CLng(yards)
        exit do
      end if
    end if
  else
    Wscript.StdOut.Write "You did not enter a number. Please try again."
  end if
loop while IsNumeric(yards) = False

'touchdowns
do
  Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many touchdowns did " & QB & " make: "
  touchdowns = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
  if IsNumeric(touchdowns) then
    touchdowns = CInt(touchdowns)
  else
    Wscript.StdOut.Write "You did not enter a number. Please try again."
  end if
loop while IsNumeric(touchdowns) = false

'interceptions
do
  Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many interceptions did " & QB & " throw: "
  interceptions = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
  if IsNumeric(interceptions) then
    interceptions = CInt(interceptions)
  else
    Wscript.StdOut.Write "You did not enter a number. Please try again."
  end if
loop while IsNumeric(interceptions) = false

'Passer rating formulae

'Percentage of completions formula
formA = (((completions / attempts) * 100) - 30) *.05
if formA < 0 then
  formA = 0
else
  if formA > 2.375 then 
    formA = 2.375
  else
    formA = FormatNumber(formA, 3)
  end if
end if

'Average yards gained per attempts formula  
formB = ((yards / attempts) - 3) * .25 
if formB < 0 then
  formB = 0
else
  if formB > 2.375 then 
    formB = 2.375
  else
    formB = FormatNumber(formB, 3)
  end if
end if

'Percentage of touchdowns formula
formC = (touchdowns / attempts) * 20
if formC > 2.375 then
  formC = 2.375
else
  formC = FormatNumber(formC, 3)
end if

'Percentage of interceptions formula
formD = 2.375 - ((interceptions / attempts) * 25)
if formD < 0 then   
  formD = 0
else
  formD = FormatNumber(formD, 3)
end if

'Summation formula
passerRating = ((formA + formB + formC + formD) / 6) * 100

Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine QB & " has a passer rating of " & FormatNumber(passerRating, 1)
```

I believe that the mathematical logic is true and correct and I also believe that all my datatype conversions are accurate. now I will give you to quarterback rating formula for players in the NFL from their [website](http://www.nfl.com/help/quarterbackratingformula).

For example, take Steve Young's record-setting season in 1994 when he completed 324 of 461 passes for 3,969 yards, 35 touchdowns, and 10 interceptions.

The four calculations would be:

- Percentage of Completions — 324 of 461 is 70.28 percent. Subtract 30
  from the completion percentage (40.28) and multiply the result by
  0.05. The result is a point rating of 2.014.  Note: If the result is less than zero (Comp. Pct. less than 30.0), award zero points. If the
  results are greater than 2.375 (Comp. Pct. greater than 77.5), award
  2.375.
- Average Yards Gained Per Attempt — 3,969 yards divided by 461
  attempts is 8.61. Subtract three yards from yards-per-attempt (5.61)
  and multiply the result by 0.25. The result is 1.403.  Note: If the
  result is less than zero (yards per attempt less than 3.0), award
  zero points. If the result is greater than 2.375 (yards per attempt
  greater than 12.5), award 2.375 points.
- Percentage of Touchdown Passes — 35 touchdowns in 461 attempts is
  7.59 percent. Multiply the touchdown percentage by 0.2. The result is 1.518.  Note: If the result is greater than 2.375 (touchdown percentage greater than 11.875), award 2.375.
- Percentage of Interceptions — 10 interceptions in 461 attempts is
  2.17 percent. Multiply the interception percentage by 0.25 (0.542) and subtract the number from 2.375. The result is 1.833.  Note: If
  the result is less than zero (interception percentage greater than
  9.5), award zero points.
- The sum of the four steps is (2.014 + 1.403 + 1.518 + 1.833) 6.768.
  The sum is then divided by six (1.128) and multiplied by 100. In this
  case, the result is 112.8. This same formula can be used to determine
  a passer rating for any player who attempts at least one pass.

I have tested this problem and isolated it down to this:

If I input:

```
Attempt: 469
Completions: 281
Yards: 1406
Touchdowns: 17
Interceptions: 15
```

However if I input this:

```
Attempts: 469
Completions: 281
Yards: 1407
Touchdowns: 17
Interceptions: 15
```

I receive an error that states:

> Runtime error - Type Mismatch 'String""

The line cursor error that comes up is on the `passerRating` variable line.

Does anyone have an idea as to what I should do to fix this problem?

Comment: I believe that `formatNumber()` function returns a String. So you are trying to add 4 strings together and it's failing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It works on the first set of numbers that I posted but not on the second. If FormatNumber was the issue wouldn't any numbers I input fail?

Comment: No. Because you have an `if` statement in there. When `passes = 1407` you get a `0` from your formula so it doesn't go to `formatNumber()`. When `passes = 1406` then the formula spits out `-0.00053` and you end up hitting `formatNumber()` and causing the addition at the end to fail since you can't add a string and a number together. Instead just pass through the result and do the `formatNumber()` last after all the arithmetic is finished.

Comment: Try `Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine formA & "|" & formB & "|" & formC & "|" & formD` _before_ the `passerRating` variable line. I guess that e.g. `formA = FormatNumber(formA, 3)` gives a non-numeric string  instead of `"2.375"`, e.g.  `"2,375"` or `" 2.375"` (note leading space) etc... Use `Round()` instead of `FormatNumber()` as follows: `formA = Round(formA, 3)`

Comment: Or use `passerRating = ((0 + formA + formB + formC + formD) / 6) * 100` to force the [behavior of the `+` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd1e4aey(v=vs.84).aspx) as arithmetic sum (with automatic conversion to number variant) instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you both JNevill and JosefZ for the enlightenment. I didn't fully understand formatNumber. I learned alot about how zero can affect data format functions. JosefZ your last comment was very simplistic and solved the issue. I will be more careful in the future with how I do calculations. I hope that this thread helps others that don"t know fully about FormatNumber. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [`FormatNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws343esk) if you want to use the number for further calculations. The purpose of the function is to produce a formatted string representation of the number for output. Remove the else branches:

```
if ... then 
  formX = 2.375
else
  formX = FormatNumber(formX, 3)
end if
```